# Why doesn't {{}} work in src attributes? Why do I need ngSrc?

Tags: angularjs

This works:

```
<a href="{{myAwesomeLink}}">It's a link. A dynamic one, at that.</a>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<img src="{{URLtoMyPerfectImage}}">
```

One needs to use `ngSrc` instead. May I know why this is the case? I had a similar problem getting a 'src' (or was it 'href'? I don't remember) to work in Handlebars.js and gave up on it (pressure for delivery).

Is this a pervasive browser issue or something similar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Extending the answer above me, while

```
<a href="{{myAwesomeLink}}">It's a link. A dynamic one, at that.</a>
```

works, it is not the best practice when dynamically creating links using Angular. Any time you use data binding in an anchor tag you should use the ng-href directive. So the code for the anchor tag should look like:

```
<a ng-href="{{myAwesomeLink}}">It's a link. A dynamic one, at that.</a>
```

Straight from Angular's documentation:

> Using Angular markup like in an href attribute makes the page open to a wrong URL, if the user clicks that link before angular has a chance to replace the with actual URL, the link will be broken and will most likely return a 404 error. The ngHref directive solves this problem.

This helps us understand ng-src: So with

```
<img src="{{imgPath}}">
```

The browser tries to load the image, but Angular has not yet replaced the bracketed expression within the src, so the image fails to load. By using

```
<img ng-src="{{imgPath}}">
```

you are telling the browser to wait to load the image until the bracketed expression has been filled in, thus loading the correct image.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc) mention this

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

If you think carefully, the javascript databinding to your html happens after the html DOM is loaded, so the browsers sees the intial src as `{{url}}` rather that a valid url string and fails.