# Why ng-src required expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

first.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="store">
 <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
     <div ng-repeat="product in store.product | orderBy:'-price'">
        <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
        <h1>{{product.price | currency}}</h1>
        <h1>{{product.description}}</h1>
        <img ng-src="{{product.image}}" />
        <button ng-show="product.canPurchase"> Add to Cart</button>
    <div>   
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
( function(){

var app=angular.module('store',[]);

app.controller('StoreController',storeFunction);

function storeFunction(){
    this.product=gem;
}

var gem=[{
    name:'Apple 5',
    price :2.95,
    description:'test description 5',
    canPurchase :true,
    image:'quick1.png'
}];

})();
```

I am learning [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), I came across ng-src and ng-show directives, I didn't understand why ng-src required expression into it to get the value where as ng-show does not required expression.

```
ng-src="{{product.image}}"  // working 
ng-src="product.image"      //not working
```

where as in the case of

```
ng-show="product.canPurchase"      //working   
ng-show="{{product.canPurchase}}"  // working
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uH1jHkqN26f8w6zNGOTx?p=preview)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648881/why-doesnt-work-in-src-attributes-why-do-i-need-ngsrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**why ng-src**

The problem is that the DOM is loaded much before angular is (because DOM initiates angular), so there is no parsing/interpolation taking place before the angular loads, but all the image tags are ready and system is starting to fetch them. At that point, the source for your image is {{product.image}} and it will try to fetch that first, returning errors.

ng-src avoids this default behaviour, and adds the src to the image once the angular is ready

**And why {{}} curlies**

because angular work in that way When an Angular page is loaded for the first time the page gets bootstrapped where the angular framework starts looking for hooks such as ng-app and ng-controller. When it knows which model it needs to use for a particular scope/code block it starts replacing all the curly braces with their expression values

this might be helpful.